# 3 dimensional array not working on php 7.1

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i got code:

```
$_SESSION['class']['id'] = $id; // 2 dimension
$_SESSION['name'][$a]['name'] = $name; // 3 dimension
$_SESSION['name'][$a]['gender'] = $gender; // 3 dimension
```

when i use php 5.6 its work just fine , but when i use php version 7.1 the code stop at

```
$_SESSION['name'][$a]['name'] = $name;
```

3 dimension array but at 2 dimension its work just finewith no error reporting. i already search in php 7.1 patch note or any article say about use multidimensional array like this will not work.

i am looking for any information why its not work on php 7.1 or i must use another type of code to make 3 multidimension array.

Comment: What you mean by "not work"? Do you get any errors?

Comment: How about `var_dump`ing `$_SESSION['name']?

Comment: i got no error the code just stop at the 3 dimension array and got no error reporting

Comment: The code cannot just stop from executing. Maybe you have error reporting turned off?

Comment: Your code works fine. https://3v4l.org/WfsYn

Comment: server i use says its php 7.1 , when i var_dump($_SESSION) after the 2 dimession its print just right , but when i var_dump($_SESSION) after the 3 dimension its show nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I experienced the same problem before. You might want to try this code.

`$_SESSION['name'][{$a}]['name']`

Comment: did you got any information why its not work use code like i use ?

Comment: sorry bro i wasn't able to remember the article that i read last time. Did it work for you?

Comment: @RickyWijaya here is the article that i read about your question https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php